# iAd Banner Not Displaying

Tags: iad

I have an iAd Banner that is not displaying. Here is my code:

The .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <iAd/iAd.h>

@interface PopViewController : UIViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate>
{

}
@end
```

The .m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[banner setAlpha:1.0];
[UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error     {
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[banner setAlpha:0];
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

The banner does not display at all. Can someone please fix this code? I have already linked the banner to files owner and made it a delegate. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've seen that code too, and it also didn't work for me. Try this instead.
Lemme know how this goes. I can help you more if it didn't work.

```
- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{

    if (banner.isBannerLoaded)
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOff" context:NULL];
        // Assumes the banner view is placed at the bottom of the screen.

        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, banner.frame.size.height);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }


}

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{

    if (!banner.isBannerLoaded)
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOn" context:NULL];
        // Assumes the banner view is just off the bottom of the screen.
        //banner.frame = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height);
        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, -banner.frame.size.height);

        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}
```